# Windows 10 does not detect Wi-Fi as metered connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, 802.11

I want Windows Wi-Fi client to detect wireless connection as *metered connection*.
I found that 802.11 protocol supports *vendor-specific information elements (IEs)*. Those IEs are injected into beacon and probe response wireless frames.

I found that Microsoft defined It's own vendor-specific IE to inform clients about metered connection over Wi-Fi ([Network Cost Element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/network-cost-information-element)) and my access point's *hostapd* supports vendor-specific features.

According to documentation for ([Network Cost Element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/network-cost-information-element)), I added vendor-specific field to `hostapd` on my OpenWRT router:

```
0xDD (Vendor-specific record)
0x08 (Record length : 8 bytes)
0x00 0x50 0xF2 (Vendor: Microsoft)
0x11 (OUI Type: Network Cost)
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 (Portable Hotspot Default: Metered network; limit unknown or not yet reached; matches Windows default for mobile broadband connections.)
```

hostapd on openwrt commands:

```
ubus call hostapd.wlan24 set_vendor_elements '{"vendor_elements": "dd080050f21100000002"}'
ubus call hostapd.wlan24 update_beacon
```

Using **CommView**, I capture wireless traffic and I see that in *Probe Response* and *Beacon* frames there is data I supplied to hostapd (last 10 bytes).

```
0x0000   80 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF-FF FF XX XX XX XX XX XX   €...ÿÿÿÿÿÿXXXXXX
0x0010   EC 41 18 50 A7 35 00 8E-99 81 50 23 98 00 00 00   ìA.P§5.Ž™.P#˜...
0x0020   64 00 31 04 00 1B YY YY-YY YY YY YY YY YY YY YY   d.1...YYYYYYYYYY
0x0030   YY YY YY YY YY YY YY YY-YY YY YY YY YY YY YY YY   YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
0x0040   XX 01 08 82 84 8B 96 0C-12 18 24 03 01 0B 05 04   Y..‚„‹–...$.....
0x0050   00 02 00 00 2A 01 00 32-04 30 48 60 6C 30 14 01   ....*..2.0H`l0..
0x0060   00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00-0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC   ...¬.....¬.....¬
0x0070   02 0C 00 0B 05 04 00 08-00 00 3B 02 51 00 2D 1A   ..........;.Q.-.
0x0080   EC 01 17 FF FF 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01   ì..ÿÿ...........
0x0090   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 3D 16 0B 00 04 00   ..........=.....
0x00A0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00B0   00 00 7F 08 04 00 00 00-00 00 01 40 DD 18 00 50   ...........@Ý..P
0x00C0   F2 02 01 01 01 00 03 A4-00 00 27 A4 00 00 42 43   ò......¤..'¤..BC
0x00D0   5E 00 62 32 2F 00 DD 08-00 50 F2 11 00 00 00 02   ^.b2/.Ý..Pò.....
```

I connect to this AP and check if connection is metered using MS Powershell on Windows PC:

```
[void][Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
[Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation]::GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetConnectionCost()
```

And get response

```
ApproachingDataLimit          : False
NetworkCostType               : Unrestricted
OverDataLimit                 : False
Roaming                       : False
BackgroundDataUsageRestricted : False
```

Where `NetworkCostType` is either `Unrestricted` or `Unknown` instead of expected `Fixed`.

When I manually set on Windows PC this connection as metered, powershell says `NetworkCostType : Fixed`

---

Some time later I found another AP (not mine, hidden) that is broadcasting beacons.
In those beacons, I found that same vendor-specific extension `0x11` by `Microsoft` is 16 bytes length and is

```
DD 10 00 50 F2 11 | 01 10 02 28 2C 30 00 00 00 01 00 00
or
DD 10 00 50 F2 11 | 01 10 02 28 2C 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 (deffers 3rd byte from the end)

0x0000   80 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF-FF FF 62 45 BD 07 36 9A   €...ÿÿÿÿÿÿbE½.6š
0x0010   62 45 BD 07 36 9A 80 71-87 80 70 00 00 00 00 00   bE½.6š€q‡€p.....
0x0020   64 00 31 C6 00 00 DD 10-00 50 F2 11 01 10 02 28   d.1Æ..Ý..Pò....(
0x0030   2C 30 00 00 00 01 00 00-                          ,0......
---
0x0000   80 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF-FF FF 62 45 BD 07 36 9A   €...ÿÿÿÿÿÿbE½.6š
0x0010   62 45 BD 07 36 9A D0 B4-16 FE 38 03 00 00 00 00   bE½.6šÐ´.þ8.....
0x0020   64 00 31 C6 00 00 DD 10-00 50 F2 11 01 10 02 28   d.1Æ..Ý..Pò....(
0x0030   2C 30 00 00 00 00 00 00-                          ,0......
```

I found that `OUI 0x11` and `Vendor 0x00 0x50 0xF2` are same - maybe MS Docs are wrong?
I've tried same on my access point with same result - data is in wireless frames, but Windows 10 does not sets connection as metered.

Any help?
Maybe I made mistake somewhere?
Maybe It is Wireless driver-dependent?
Maybe MS have docs but did not implemented it in desktop systems?

---

**Setting `Metered connection` manually is not the way I want to solve this problem.**

Answer (score 3):

1. There <s>is</s> **[was](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/pull/2810)** a mistake in [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/network-cost-information-element):
   Correct packet is `DD080050F211??00**00`, where `??` is `Cost Level` and `**` is `Cost Flags`

**Cost Levels:**

- `00 Unknown`      - The connection cost is unknown.
- `01 Unrestricted` - The connection is unlimited and has unrestricted usage constraints.
- `02 Fixed`        - Usage counts toward a fixed allotment of data which the user has already paid for (or agreed to pay for).
- `04 Variable`     - The connection cost is on a per-byte basis.

**Cost Flags:**

- `00 Unknown`                - The usage is unknown or unrestricted.
- `01 Over Data Limit`        - Usage has exceeded the data limit of the metered network; different network costs or conditions might apply.
- `02 Congested`              - The network operator is experiencing or expecting heavy load.
- `04 Roaming`                - The tethering connection is roaming outside the provider's home network or affiliates.
- `08 Approaching Data Limit` - Usage is near the data limit of the metered network; different network costs or conditions might apply once the limit is reached.

**[Correct MS Docs MS-NCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nct/)**

---

2. Seems that when you manually trigger the `Metered connection` switch, Windows ignores 802.11 IE until you forget network (or maybe not).

---

For OpenWRT access point my *epic* issue resulting in 4 commands

```
uci add_list wireless.radio0.hostapd_options='vendor_elements=DD080050F21102000200'
uci add_list wireless.radio1.hostapd_options='vendor_elements=DD080050F21102000200'
uci commit
reboot
```

*I've added `Fixed` cost level with `Congested` flag. Don't know if Congested affects anything.*

`hostapd_options` is undocumented parameter in /etc/config/wireless (or `uci radio?.hostapd_options`), [but it exists since 2017](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/19bf1642912b120403d52bf685818b10e3736079/package/network/services/hostapd/files/hostapd.sh#L218)